# Does overriding CSS affect the entire SharePoint sites in that server?

Tags: css, sharepoint, overriding, sharepoint-2019

I need to write an Override.CSS for a SharePoint site. While I have other multiple sites on the same server, Does writing the overriding CSS affect other sites on the same server too? if yes, how to override the CSS without affecting other sites? Thanks for your time...much appreciated

Comment: Do you want to override CSS in a webpart? Or do you want to override CSS elsewhere? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I am trying to override CSS for the SharePoint generic navbar. I am trying to upload a override.css file to make it work but that's not overriding atm. Its SharePoint 2019 communication site